# Convert php to c#

Tags: c#, php

I found this PHP source, but needed it in C#.

How would I convert this?

```
return "*".strtoupper(sha1(sha1($password, 1), 0));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        var resulta = sha.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("password"));
        var resultb = sha.ComputeHash(resulta);

        return "*" + BitConverter.ToString(resultb).Replace("-","");
```

Comment: Hey Andy, where does it get upper cased?

Comment: The output of the bitconvertor is uppercase automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's break down the components:

- strtoupper
- sha1

How to do `strtoupper` in C#:

```
string password = password.ToUpper();
```

How to do SHA1 in C#:

```
SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 
result = sha.ComputeHash(data);
```

You will also have to convert the string to a byte array to use it in the hash:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
return encoding.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: Wouldnt it also have a `*`?

Comment: Correct, if you wanted that :)  Good attention to detail.  I'll let the OP figure that one out for themselves

Comment: You don't want to upper the password, you want to upper the hash.